# A concurrency-safe stack structure

Tags: f#

This is a teaching sample intended to illustrate use of mutability and list consing in F#.  The structure is intended to be a thread-safe stack structure, which multiple threads can push to/pop from concurrently.  Concerns:

- Will this actually be thread safe?
- Are the locks necessary?
- Is there an immutable way to do the same thing?  I don't think one can use the traditional immutable method here of having the Push/Pop return a new stack instance because different clients will see divergent views of the stack.

The code looks like this:

```
type ConcurrentStack<'T>() =    
    let mutable _stack : List<'T> = []

    member this.Push value =
      lock _stack (fun () -> 
         _stack <- value :: _stack)

    member this.TryPop() =
      lock _stack (fun () ->
         match _stack with
         | result :: newStack ->
            _stack <- newStack
            result |> Some
         | [] -> None
      )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will this actually be thread safe?

Yes, I think it will.  All access to the `_stack` field is protected by a lock, so I do not see why this wouldn't be thread safe.

A nice coincidence of using immutable lists is that you can also nicely implement `IEnumerable<'T>` or even just return the list of all elements currently in the stack - because the data type is immutable, it can be safely shared with other threads (this means, you won't get into the usual troubles with *"Collection was modified; enumeration operation cannot continue"* that you'd get in C#.

> Are the locks necessary?

I think so. Without the lock, one thread could start evaluating `Push` by evaluating `value::_stack`, then another thread could modify `_stack` and the original thread would then overwrite `_stack` with the *old* value of `value::_stack` (and so the effect of the other thread would be lost!)

> Is there an immutable way to do the same thing? I don't think one can use the traditional immutable method here of having the Push/Pop return a new stack instance because different clients will see divergent views of the stack.

If the idea is to have multiple threads sharing the state, then they'll need some way of sharing & mutating the state. Another approach in F# would be to use an agent and keep the current `_stack` as a parameter of the asynchronous loop - in that case, you're not using mutation in the F# code you write (but there is hidden mutation and synchronization going on in the agent).

Logically, the agent-based version is quite similar to the one you have using locks - it might be a bit nicer for other reasons (getting locks right is hard, agents do not make it possible to do the same kinds of errors), but that really depends on what you want to illustrate!

Comment: Thanks Tomas. Looks like that'll be safe to put in my PluralSight course. Terrified of spreading misinformation!

Answer (score 1):

> Are the locks necessary?

Some synchronization is necessary, but it doesn't necessarily have to be a lock.

Another option would be to use [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb297966.aspx). But doing that is more complicated, so I would stick with the lock, unless profiling showed that the lock is what's slowing your code down.